Polars - How to load large size Google BigQuery table into a polars DataFrame?
I've been trying to load BigQuery tables into polars DataFrame (on Vertex AI Jupyter Notebook - GCP) and work on them, there are some tables in my dataset which have around 500 to 600 GB of size and around 100 millions of rows. I tried loading them into a polars DataFrame, but for obvious reasons (such as memory constraints) the kernel is crashing.
For smaller size BigQuery tables, the traditional way of loading and converting into DataFrame is working, as shown below:
import polars as pl
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

converted_df = pl.from_arrow(client.query(f"SELECT * FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.table_1`").to_arrow())

But when I tried the same way for the bigger tables, it doesn't work. The kernel stops itself.

Specify what you've tried to handle large data (e.g., chunking, pagination) and any specific errors encountered.

I'm new to polars, so I don't know how to do both (chunking, pagination) for such large data. When I try to load the table, The kernel just stops due to overload of memory.

So first of all, your issue is not Polars related. It is your SQL query which is extremely inefficient and scans the whole table. But in this case, if your kernel crashes, make sure you have enough RAM and CPU to process the dataframe.

I see, thanks @geometricfreedom for the comment. I will try increasing the resources.

Try so,  but also try to optimize your SQL query.

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17326 is the feature request to add a scan_bigquery function, allowing the streaming processor to help with the chunking for you. I recommend watching that issue for updates in future.

Thank you for the comment @TimSwast, I will definitely have an eye on that issue.

Chunking is the right answer. Implementation is up for debate.
so you can either use the limit and offset on sql side to handle the chunking or so something with the looping through streamed results part. (with the write a file for each chunk method ive gotten great results with the sql limit part being thrown to multiple processes (multiprocessing.pool)
the basic logic is to the lines of loop through every result and make a batch of them then when that batch is full write it to a file and "clear memory" for the next batch. this obviously only works if you stream in the results. i use sqlalchemy and oracle which allows for this so your results may vary
# just a helper function since we need to add this in 2 places
def write_temp_file(records,schema,filename):
    bdf = polars.LazyFrame(records, schema=schema, orient="row")
    bdf.sink_parquet(filename, compression="snappy")
    def bdf # probably not necessary
    return filename

files = []
temp_records = []

result = await conn.session.stream(query.execution_options(yield_per=1000))

async for row in result: # result is an async generator here
    # i turn my result into a pydantic model first so use `temp_records.append(MyModel(**row._mapping))` to turn the dict result into the model and then add the model to the temp data list 
    temp_records.append(row)

    # now to do some chunking
    if len(temp_records) >= 100000: #batch size
        # generate a temp filename based on how many there already are
        filename = f"tmp-{len(files)}.parquet"
        # call a helper fun and keep track of the files we have made
        files.append(write_temp_file(temp_records,schema,filename))
        # reset the temp records
        temp_records = []

# the batches will only hit if it gets to that count. so if there are still temp_records remaining we need to write them up as well
if len(temp_records):
    filename = f"tmp-{len(files)}.parquet"
    files.append(write_temp_file(temp_records,schema,filename))
    
# we now have a nice and shiney lazyframe that's the combination of all our chunks. polars lets you add a list of files as the input to scan_xxx
lazyframe = polars.scan_parquet(files,hive_schema=schema)
# we can now merge them into 1
lazyframe.sink_parquet("the_aggregated_file.parquet")

# cleanup the temp files
for file in self.files:
    if os.path.exists(file):
        os.remove(file)



Given the large size of the tables you're working with, it's understandable that loading the entire dataset into memory is causing the kernel to crash. To handle large datasets like this, you might alternative approaches.
I have used the below 2 approaches,
Approach 1: Chunked Loading
One can load the data in smaller pieces instead of loading the table fully into memory. They can then be processed and saved as results on disk or, alternatively, aggregated in real time.
from google.cloud import bigquery
import polars as pl

client = bigquery.Client()
chunk_size = 10000  

query = f"SELECT * FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.table_1`"
query_job = client.query(query)
total_rows = query_job.total_rows

chunks = []
for i in range(0, total_rows, chunk_size):
    partial_query = f"{query} LIMIT {chunk_size} OFFSET {i}"
    partial_result = client.query(partial_query).to_arrow()
    chunks.append(pl.from_arrow(partial_result))

final_df = pl.concat(chunks)

Approach 2: Using Dask or Ray with Polars
Dask or Ray could be combined with Polars, which gives parallel processing and distributed computing. It comes in quite handy when scaling the workload across many workers.
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
import polars as pl

client = Client()  

def load_data(query):
    bq_client = bigquery.Client()
    result = bq_client.query(query).to_arrow()
    return pl.from_arrow(result)

ddf = dd.from_delayed([
    dask.delayed(load_data)(f"{query} LIMIT {chunk_size} OFFSET {i}")
    for i in range(0, total_rows, chunk_size)
])

df = ddf.compute()  



This looks dangerously close to AI generated.. Just copying the question to chatGPT gives a very similar result.

As AI gets data from open internet. Approach 1 was used by me already. Approach 2 is discussed in reddit too. I tried Chatgpt after seeing your comment, but it gives me additional 2 ways, but in that 1 approach won't even solve the issue.

The rows that are returned by LIMIT and OFFSET have undefined order unless these clauses are used after ORDER BY. - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit_and_offset_clause. Your code does not do chunking but processing random rows.
